# Validate function to check file extension from database

Tags: javascript

I need to validate the extension of an uploading file in js.I have successfully created a fuction like as follows.

```
function FileExtension_Validate(txt)
{
if( !txt.match(/\.(pdf)|(doc)|(PDF)|(DOC)|(docx)|(DOCX)$/)) { return false; } else  {return true; }
}
```

But now my situation is, i have a database field which have data as follows

> pdf,doc,PDF,DOC,docx,DOCX

Now i need to create a function based on the data from database.Is there any possible solution.Please help me..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows..

```
function FileExtension_Validate(txt)
{
    //alert(txt);
    var extension=document.getElementById('extension').value;
     var piece = extension.split(',');
     var split=extension.split(',').length
     var flag=0;
    //alert(piece[0]);
      for (var i = 0; i <split; i++) 
         {
             var test=piece[i];
             //alert(test);
             if( txt!=test) { flag++;} 
               //else  {return true; }
         }
        // alert(flag);
         if(flag==split)
         {
          return false;
         }
         else{
    return true;
    }
```

in `extension` i have passed the extension of the uploade file